How do I connect the other hard disk to the server
How do I connect the other hard disk to the server
I have a server that has a basic SSD hard disk for the system and another hard disk has been installed. How do I connect them to the server so that one of them works as a home and the other is for a backup copy
See the two hard disks 2.5T 0 disk
2.5T 0 disk
To be connected to the server
sda 8:0 0 2.5T 0 disk
└─sda1 8:1 0 2.5T 0 part

sdb 8:16 0 2.5T 0 disk
└─sdb1 8:17 0 2.5T 0 part

nvme0n1 259:0 0 477G 0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1 0 511M 0 part 
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2 0 20.5G 0 part │
   └─md2 9:2 0 20.5G 0 raid1 /boot 
├─nvme0n1p3 259:3 0 377.7G 0 part │ 
   └─md3 9:3 0 377 .5G 0 raid1 /
├─nvme0n1p4 259:4 0 5.1G 0 part [SWAP


You've not provided any Ubuntu product & release details; so we can only be generic.  Why not create a mount point, and tell your system via its file-system table exactly what you want & thus get it.   Adjust for your unstated product & release details.

OS
AlmaLinux v8.10.0 STANDARD standard
cPanel Version
120.0.14

Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.

You should remove the PHP tag from your post.
